# How to add padding downwards in a bootstrap card?

Tags: html, django

I want to add padding on all four sides of a bootstrap card, and so used the attribute `style='padding:25px'`, but padding is only being applied on the other three sides except downwards, i.e there are no padding between rows. How do I fix this? I am using django and htm

```
<div class="row" style='padding:25px'>
      {% for player in players %}
         <div class="col-auto col-md-3">
            <div class="column">
               <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" width="20" height="300" src="{{ player.image_url }}">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">{{ player.name }}</h5>
                     <p class="card-text">{{ player.position }}</p>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Know More!</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this :

```
<div class="row" style='padding:25px'>
      {% for player in players %}
         <div class="col-auto col-md-3">
            <div class="column" style='padding:25px'>
               <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" width="20" height="300" src="{{ player.image_url }}">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">{{ player.name }}</h5>
                     <p class="card-text">{{ player.position }}</p>
```